# Gradle dependency conflicts after adding firebase performance dependency

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, firebase-performance

After adding:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.1.0
```

I started getting

```
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules jetified-proto-google-common-protos-1.18.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.18.0) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.1.1-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.1.1)
```

However when I start to exclude some packages from com.google.firebase then the project

```
  configurations {
    implementation.exclude module:'proto-google-common-protos'
    implementation.exclude module: 'protobuf-java'
  }
```

the project started to compile with some warnings

```
> Task :app:transformClassesWithFirebasePerformancePluginForAccDebug
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/marshalling/ByteInput
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/marshalling/ByteInput
```

This is a point I cannot go forward.

Please find my dependency tree at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aGxb2_qkhcRVRZv2lCI0nmoYxwy77h0V/view?usp=sharing